Styling a PyQT push button for rich text with QSS for different text and background-color in checked state
I have created a push button QPushButtonRT capable of rendering rich text from QPushButton and QLabel (which works). The code is taken from another StackOverflow question but I forgot to write down the OP - sorry!
Styling the background-color of QPushButtonRT depending on checked / unchecked state with a QSS file works well. However, styling the text color of the underlying QLabel does not work the way I think it should.
QPushButtonRT
class QPushButtonRT(QPushButton):
    """
    Subclass QPushButton, using QLabel to render rich text
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, text=None, margin=10, **kwargs):
        if parent is not None:
            super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.margin = margin
        if text is not None:
            self.__lbl.setText(text)
        self.__lyt = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        # Make QLabel transparent except for painted pixels:
        self.__lbl.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Disable delivery of mouse events to QLabel and its children,
        # passing the events along to QPushButton:
        self.__lbl.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.__lbl.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.__lbl.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__lbl, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        return

    def setText(self, text):
        self.__lbl.setText(text)
        self.updateGeometry()
        return

    def sizeHint(self):
        is_checked = self.isChecked()
        self.setChecked(False)  # always base sizeHint on unchecked state
        s = QPushButton.sizeHint(self)
        w = self.__lbl.sizeHint()
        s.setWidth(w.width() + 2 * self.margin)
        self.setChecked(is_checked)
        return s

QSS file
QPushButton{background-color: #505050;}         /* background for both QPushButton and QPushButtonRT */
.QPushButton{color: white; font-weight: bold;}  /* text color QPushButton only */

QPushButton QLabel{color:white; font-weight: bold;} /* text color QPushButtonRT only (1) */
QPushButton:checked QLabel{color:black;}            /* text color QPushButtonRT only (2) */

/* Define 'border' to avoid "grey dots" due to transparent border overlay
   https://forum.qt.io/topic/41325/solved-background-of-checked-qpushbutton-with-stylesheet
*/
QPushButton:checked {background-color:lightblue; border: none;} /* QPushButton and QPushButtonRT */
.QPushButton:checked{color:black; font-weight: bold;} /* QPushButton only */

/* The same effect is achieved by using one of
QPushButtonRT:checked > QLabel{color:black;}
QPushButton:checked > QLabel{color:black;}
   to define the text color of QPushButtonRT  */

Switching the background color of both QPushButton and QPushButtonRT widgets depending on the checked state works well, but text color is only switched for QPushButton.
The really strange thing is that only the order of lines (1) and (2) determines the text color of QPushButtonRT, disregarding checked state.

The descendant selector is only based on the class of the parent, not its states. The order matters because the state is completely ignored, and the second rule overrides the first. What you want cannot be achieved with QSS only. The only work around you may have is to write QLabel rules depending on the enabled/disabled state, and then connect the toggled signal of the button to setEnabled() of the label.

Thanks, I didn't know that states are ignored - now I understand the behaviour. I'd like to accept your answer, unfortunately this is only a comment.
